# Redirect command to a file inside bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I've created a bash script, and inside it I want to run a program, `pihole -up`. I want to be able to redirect the output from this program to a file, either line by line or after completion

I've so far tried a variety of options

```
pihole -up || log.txt
pihole -up > log.txt
(pihole -up) > log.txt
```

No matter what I try I seem to get a garbled file out like so `'log.txt'$'\r'`

The output is right, but the file name is wrong. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Did you create your script using a Windows text editor?

Comment: You **pipe** the output of program A into the input of program B. You **redirect** the output of a program into a file. The second option should work, once you fix the line endings in your script.